# How to avoid getting warnings from Google about render problems due to robots.txt when there is Facebook content on our site?

Tags: google-search-console

It's quite weird that Google seems to try to crawl some Facebook content, which makes me get a warning. How do I avoid this?

[image]

Comment: What are you using on your page from Facebook?  Is it a like button, or embedded content?

Comment: And your domain is entirely unrelated (eg. `example.com`)?

Comment: The domain is absolutely related and relevant

Answer (score 1):

This alert isn't relevant for your site's rating and ranking. Google absolutely realizes, that it crawls a third party ressource, and Google knows the web situation profound enough to understand, that you don't control crawling of  scripts hosted by Facebook ;)

But with the very high paranoia level you could host Facebook scripts locally and allow their crawling. Some webmasters are doing so, because of paranoia or because of performance - i've read reports about achievings of performance gains (because of less requests through the web). But this is personally for me rather a kind of religious question - i guess, performance gains are in the scope of `‰`.